# Microsoft Excel formula for variance

Tags: variance, excel, unbiased-estimator

According to Microsoft Excel Help:

> VAR uses the following formula:
> [image: Formula]
>
> where x is the sample mean
> AVERAGE(number1,number2,…) and n is
> the sample size.

Shouldn't it be n, rather than n - 1, in the denominator?

Comment: @onestop The "statistical-bias" tag is somewhat confusing here.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. The guidelines suggest updating tags in light of the the answers as well as the original question, so I was wondering if there was a tag for 'unbiased estimator' or 'unbiasedness', but there wasn't, so i used 'statistical bias' on the grounds that separate tags for flip sides of the same coin seem a bit unecessary, and the guidelines favor reuse of existing tags over creation of new ones. I'm about to fall sleep but I'll take another look at this in the morning.

Comment: I changed statistical-bias to unbiased-estimator. Does that work?

Comment: Fine with me. I've just added this new tag to a few other old posts - what do you think? Also does the "statistical bias" tag still have a place? If so, when would you use it? Is this what the "tag wiki" system is meant to be for? I'm afraid I haven't worked out if or how i can edit that. Maybe we should take this to meta...

Comment: @Skrikant In fact, I didn't think another tag was needed at all, but yours looks better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use VARP for the variance you want ("population variance").  VAR is the unbiased estimator for a normally distributed population.

Comment: VAR is unbiased for any distribution with a finite variance, not just for the normal distribution.

Comment: Right, whatever variance mean when the distribution is not close to normal ;-)

Comment: @mbq to some, the variance is a moment of inertia. there is also chebyshev's inequality, that applies to any distribution. it also has an interpretation similar to that for the normal for any location/scale family with a finite second moment - like the logistic, for example. [the pdfs need not be symmetric, tho.]

Comment: altho, as whuber points out, there are two excel functions for variance, if my recollection is correct, there is only one for covariance - and it divides by n, not n-1. [i haven't checked the latest version of excel, tho. can someone tell us if that is still the case?]

Comment: @ronaf Allegedly Excel 2010 now has both, COVARIANCE.P and COVARIANCE.S.  However, the documentation is so dismal one cannot really be sure!  (In the older versions if you know about covariance at all you're probably knowledgeable enough to be able to multiply the result by n/(n-1) in the formula.)  For more info visit http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/statistical-functions-reference-HP010342920.aspx

Answer (score 12):

Use VAR (with n-1 denominator) when you wish to estimate the variance of the underlying population from the sample, or VARP (with n denominator) when the sample *is* the population.

I find the name "population variance" quite ambiguous...

Comment: Crystal clear! I find the name "population variance" ambiguous too.